# Angular JS select box from table cell disabled

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have html code with AngularJS like below for select box inside table cell.

```
 <td>                              
   <select ng-model="row.status" ng-change="toggle_syslog_filter(row.id,row.status)" >
       <option value="0">Disabled</option>
       <option value="1">Enabled ( Log Only )</option>
       <option value="2">Enabled ( Alerts Active )</option>
   </select>
   <span style="color:red;">
       <i class="fa fa-remove" ng-click="delete_filter(row.id)"></i>
   </span>                                    
 </td>
```

but it adds some classes to select box

```
<td>                                               
     <select ng-model="row.status" ng-change="toggle_syslog_filter(row.id,row.status)" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">
        <option value="0">Disabled</option>
        <option value="1">Enabled ( Log Only )</option>
        <option value="2">Enabled ( Alerts Active )</option>
     </select>
     <span style="color:red;">
         <i class="fa fa-remove" ng-click="delete_filter(row.id)"></i>
     </span>                                             
 </td>
```

it adds the classes

> ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched

and it made the select box disabled.

Comment: here is the documentation for ngModel https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel which explains what these css classes are and what they mean..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what is happening is because of ng-change basically **ng-change directive tells AngularJS what to do when the value of an HTML element changes.**
So it might be possible that the expression evaluating in ng-change is false. Just for the sake of checking try putting the value of ng-change to ng-change='True' and see if it still disable. Because pristine valid and touched are used to validate if the input field